# Data type compatibility in C to Mysql

Tags: mysql, c

I got one issue while implementing the `Ctime()` in C using MS VC++ 2008 for running the application.

By using the `ctime` I will get current time format as *Sun Jan 09 14:38:09 2011*. Is there any way to convert the above format as *2012-01-09 14:38:09* (in MYSQL). Is there any direct functions in C.

Any suggestion to do this?

Comment: You can convert your `time_t` to a `struct tm` with [`localtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html) (or [`gmtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gmtime.html)), then use [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html) to format the date as you want.

Comment: Thanks  pmg.ur idea worked..one more doubt .If i want to insert the current time in three fileds in atable.But the three timings should differ slightly.Is it possible to do? NOw i can all the three fileds contains same timing.eg:12:05,12:08,12:10..like this?

Comment: Get 3 different `time_t` values. Convert them to `struct tm` and format each one as you want. Example: `time_t t0 = time(0); time_t t1 = t0 + 3600; time_t t2 = t0 + 24*3600;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your `time_t` to a `struct tm` with [`localtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html) (or [`gmtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gmtime.html)), then use [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html) to format the date as you want.

Example:

```
char out[20];
time_t t0 = time(0);
struct tm *tm0 = localtime(t0);
strftime(out, sizeof out, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tm0);
```

---

If you need different `time_t` values for different database columns, create them.
Then convert to `struct tm` and format each one as above.
Example:

```
time_t t0 = time(0);       /* now */
time_t t1 = t0 + 3600;     /* 1 hour from now */
time_t t2 = t0 + 24*3600;  /* 1 day (24 hours) from now */
```

*posted from comments to enable OP to accept as answer*

Answer (score 0):

According to `man ctime()`:

> The asctime() and mktime() functions both take an argument
>   representing broken-down time which is a representation separated into
>   year, month, day, etc.

I guess you can use these other functions to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one in C. Use mktime (or mktime_r) and sprintf to create your own time format.

Comment: make that sprintf( ), not printf( )

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the one and only way to handle this (or any other) mismatch is to store the raw value returned by time() in your table; and then to let any application (including yours) format that value into any arrangement it wants to show the user.

This approach offers three big wins:

1. It takes advantage of the universal, simple, and well-documented time_t format, meaning you can give the db away and be sure that anybody can interpret and handle it with no further work/documentation for you. struct tm and ctime-like formats are completely arbitrary, chosen by some poor midnight programmer thirty years ago.
2. You avoid the well-deserved scorn and anger directed at you by anybody who wants to implement internationalization in what used to be your code.
3. Most important: it stores time in a format that you or anybody else can sort/select on, which is not true of any others.

It's foundational, I believe, that your table be as widely understood as you can make it. You can meet this goal by storing raw, time_t values.